# Team City: Get artifacts from a build prior to another build

Tags: teamcity

I would like to create a build configuration which compares the results of a build, with the build before it.

In the web UI, adding an artifact dependency, the only options that looks like it could do what I want, is "Get artifcacts from: Build with specified build number", but knowing what to put in the build number box is tricky! I can't do maths in there, and even if I can, our VCS is Perforce, and changelists are not always sequential due to e.g. local/shelved changelists.

I imagine this means I need to write a script to access the REST API, so I need to figure out a build locator to get the artifacts I want... but I'm not sure what the dimensions I should specify are. Is there some combination that can give me the build *before* a given VCS revision number? Or will I have to walk backwards using `revision:<REVISION>` until I find one that exists? That feels messy!

Answer (score 1):

To get the last finished "normal" build (from default branch, not personal, not canceled) from the same build configuration as your build you can use URL like .../app/rest/builds/buildType:(id:%system.teamcity.buildType.id%)
(from within the build you can authenticate with %system.pin.builds.user.name%:%system.pin.builds.user.password%)

However, if you need to get the previous build regarding changes (e.g. it can be not the last one), it will be more tricky.

Comment: Thanks! I'd really like to get the previous build in terms of changes though, to avoid comparing two builds with the same changes, or a build several changes ago (in case of overlapping builds - several could be in progress at once!). I thought about this some more, and it seems like my 'messy' suggestion is the only one that'll work, because of the overlapping builds situation - it would be too much to ask for TC to provide a way to block fetching artifacts until the build the creates them has finished!

Comment: You can achieve "block fetching artifacts until the build the creates them has finished" with the snapshot dependencies